# How to remove a SPAN create with APPEND()?

Tags: class, jquery-selectors

I have this code

> BOX

and After:

> $(".boxAlert").click(function(){
>     $(this).remove();
>     //$(this).fadeOut(500);     });

It's OKAY, when I click on the SPAN with class boxAlert, it removes it.

But I can not remove the SPAN's I created this way..

> $('#myDiv').append('Invalid Mail');

The SPAN I create this way appears in the page and has the class boxAlert, applied, but I can not remove it or fadeOut or anything..

Any ideas?

Comment: Ups, sorry, I did a mistake copyng my code.... I will fix it in the post if I can.
But my Correct code is : $('#myDiv').append('<span class="boxAlert">Invalid Mail</span>');
Will take a look to test...

Comment: Okay,, I have EDIT my mistake sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
$(".boxAlert").live('click', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

The `live()` methods works for elements present now or those coming in future.

Comment: Work like a charm... I think indeed that this objects weren't not in the page when code was ready... But didn't know nothing about "live"... I've learn something new today.. And still a lot to learn.
Thanks for your help...
Pedro